# Unable to introduce a subquery to the COUNT

Tags: sql, oracle

The query I am trying to produce is view the NAME of the guest with the most visits to a restaurants, the code below outputs GuestID and number of visits but i am struggling to link the Visits table to the Guest Table and have the output GuestName and count.

Whenever I would introduce GuestN.Gname i would get a 'A group function is not allowed or a group function not needed'

```
    SELECT GuestN.GID, COUNT(VisitN.GID) as cnt
    FROM VisitN
    JOIN GuestN ON VisitN.GID = GuestN.GID
    GROUP BY VisitN.GID
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

To clarify the Visit table has the GID and and amount of restaurant visited and my Guest table has the guest name and GID

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the name in the `select` and `group by`, if you want it:

```
SELECT g.GID, g.Name, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM VisitN v JOIN
     GuestN g
     ON v.GID = g.GID
GROUP BY g.GID, g.Name
ORDER BY cnt DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```